# VBA Code to Stop Running Current Code after It is complete

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the cells value "Details" and delete that row along with the 3 rows below it.

The code I current have works but once there are no longer any cells with "Details", I get the error box asking me to end the macro or debug.

How do I fix current code and eliminate the error message box from popping up.

My current code is below.

```
Dim StartRange As String
Dim EndRange As String
For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1000")
    Cells.Find(What:="Details").Select
    StartRange = ActiveCell.Address
    Selection.Offset(3, 75).Select
    EndRange = ActiveCell.Address
    ActiveSheet.Range(StartRange & ":" & EndRange).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Next Cell
```

Comment: What is the error message exactly, and which line/instruction is the VBA editor highlighting when you click "debug"?

Comment: That said, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513) would be a relevant read.

Comment: It's not clear what your code is doing. It's iterating over 1000 cells but searches for `Details` all over the sheet. Be aware, that `Find` searches for partial result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - note, it's best to fully qualify `Range` with your `Workbook` and `Worksheet` name (i.e. `Workbooks("MyWorkbook").Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range()`.

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long

For i = 10000 To 1 Step -1
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "details" Then
        Range("B" & i & ":B" & i + 3).EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf Range("V" & i).Value = "pending renewal" Then
        Range("V" & i & ":V" & i + 7).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i - 3, "A"))` is lookin' better :)

Comment: @JohnyL Either of them would look better with fully qualified calls to `Range` or `Cells`.

Comment: @Comintern OP never provided any workbook or worksheet names, so an unqualified `Range` might as well be just as effective as his use of `ActiveSheet` - I think it's beyond the point until he provides more details.

Comment: I guess `i + 3` - not `i - 3`

Comment: @JohnyL Stepping backwards, but I did change it to `Range("A" & i - 3 & ":A" & i).EntireRow.Delete` ;)

Comment: OP says `3 rows` below! :) That's why you need `+` instead of `-` :)

Comment: @Comintern *another poor practice* The qualifying ain't relevant in OP's context. That's why I asked you don't start with this...

Comment: Thanks for the code above! It does exactly what I needed it to do. I would like to do the same thing based on a few other criteria found in different columns, but when i replicate the code and change it to find the next criteria, only one of the codes works. The code i have written is below. Also, i am relatively new at using VBA so sorry if i am asking simple/dumb questions

Comment: Dim i As Long

For i = 10000 To 1 Step -1
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "Details" Then
        Range("B" & i & ":B" & i + 3).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

Dim j As Long

For j = 10000 To 1 Step -1
    If Range("V" & j).Value = "Pending renewal" Then
        Range("V" & j & ":V" & j + 7).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next j

Comment: @MacMacDonald Looks fine to me - see my edited answer above. No need for a new variable or another loop.

Comment: @dwirony Thanks. when i inputed the edited code, it is still only removing the rows with "Pending renewal" and not those with "Details"

Comment: @MacMacDonald Is "Details" in column A or B? In your modified code you changed column A to B - also do you have 10,000 rows or only 1000?

Comment: @dwirony "Details" is in column B, and there are 10,000 rows. I mistakenly coded it wrong in my first post.

Comment: @MacMacDonald Should be working... are you sure it's just "Details" in the cell? No trailing/leading white space? You said it was working fine the first time but now it's not? I can't reproduce your issue. I've edited the code to use `InStr` just in case... otherwise, double check those columns.

Comment: @dwirony I figured out what my issue was. The D in Details was not capitalized so the code was not finding it. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: @MacMacDonald Ah, in that case you can even put `Option Compare Text` above `Sub Test()` and it will ignore all cases :)